# How to get GoogleSignInAccount object when signing in with Google Play Games Services V2

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services

I'm building an android game with java and I'm adding logging in my users with **Google Play Games Services V2** and **Firebase**.

I have no problem integrating the code from the Play Games website (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin#migrate_to_play_games_services_sign_in_v2) but when it comes to Firebases website (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games) I'm stuck.

There is a crucial method `firebaseAuthWithPlayGames()` and it requires GoogleSignInAccount object but I don't know how to get it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you found a solution how to get GoogleSignInAccount from Google Play Games v2 sign in method? Actually we need only AuthCredential to pass in firebaseAuthWithPlayGames().

```
AuthCredential credential = PlayGamesAuthProvider.getCredential(googleSignInAccount.getServerAuthCode());
```

But how to get this GoogleSignInAccount?
May be GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(appContext); will pass, I haven't checked it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need only AuthCode from PlayGamesClient you can get it like this:

```
val gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(this) /* Activity */
    gamesSignInClient
        .requestServerSideAccess(
            getString(R.string.default_web_client_id),  /* Your web client id */
            false
        )
        .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<String?> ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val serverAuthToken = task.result
                if (serverAuthToken != null) {
                    firebaseAuthWithPlayGames(serverAuthToken)
                }
                
            } else {
                // Failed to retrieve authentication code.
                Toast.makeText(
                    baseContext,
                    "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                ).show()
            }
        }

private fun firebaseAuthWithPlayGames(serverAuthCode: String) {
    val auth = Firebase.auth
    val credential = PlayGamesAuthProvider.getCredential(serverAuthCode)
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                val user = auth.currentUser

            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(
                    baseContext,
                    "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                ).show()

            }

            // ...
        }
}
```